# Prevent calling javascript function on disable radiobuttonlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdStatus" onclick="javacript:display();" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
<asp:ListItem Text="Temporary Waiver" Value="T" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Never Expires" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>    
<asp:ListItem Text="Expires after the close of:" Value="W"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My Problem:

- during run this code html table is created for radio button list and on click event is placed on table.
- even i disable the radiobutton list , the click event is occur. I need to avoid this issue . Please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On disable radio buttons add class as "disabled" to radio buttons & better way to use jQuery insted of javascript as bellow

```
jQuery("#rdStatus").click(function()`{  

    if(jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled"))
        return false;

    continue with you code here.............
}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote does exactly what you asked it to do: when the user clicks on the element, the function is run.
There are two ways you can change it to get your desired efect:

1. Use another event instead of onclick
2. Stop the function execution

**Another event**

You might want to look towards the CHANGE event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)

**Stop function**

Inside the function you can check the state of your RadioButtonList. If it is disabled, you simply `return;` from the function instead of running the actual useful code. If you don't want to alter the original function, you can write a small wrapper that calls it only if the RadioButtonList is enabled and use the wrapper as handler for the 'click' event.